# How to extract value from json and increment

Tags: python, dictionary

Sample json is below. I want to save `id` which is completed (False and True) into seperated dictionaryies

```
todos = [{'userId': 1, 'id': 1, 'title': 'delectus aut autem', 'completed': False},
 {'userId': 1, 'id': 2, 'title': 'quis ut nam facil ', 'completed': False},
 {'userId': 1, 'id': 1, 'title': 'fugiat veniam minus', 'completed': False},
 {'userId': 1, 'id': 2, 'title': 'et porro tempora', 'completed': True},
 {'userId': 1, 'id': 1,'title': 'laprovident illum', 'completed': False}]
```

Expected out is below

```
todos_by_user_true = {1:0,2:1}
todos_by_user_false = {1:3,2:1}
```

code is below? Why my code not working. I am getting blank dictionary

```
todos_by_user_true = {}
todos_by_user_false = {}
# Increment complete TODOs count for each user.
for todo in todos:
    if todo["completed"]==True:
        try:
            # Increment the existing user's count.
            todos_by_user_true[todo["id"]] += 1
        except KeyError:
            # This user has not been seen. Set their count to 1.
            todos_by_user_true[todo["id"]] = 0
    elif todo["completed"]==False:
        try:
            # Increment the existing user's count.
            todos_by_user_false[todo["id"]] += 1
        except KeyError:
            # This user has not been seen. Set their count to 1.
            todos_by_user_false[todo["id"]] = 0
```

I am getting not proper dictionary

My output is below

todos_by_user_false `{1: 2, 2: 0}`

todos_by_user_true `{2: 0}`

Disclaimer: I need to take care of exception also

Comment: stating the obvious but you are not using `todos_by_user_true` and `todos_by_user_false` anywhere in the code.

Comment: @VishalSingh rectified the problem

Comment: What does the key and value mean `{1:0,2:1}` ?

Comment: You want to save `id` but you are checking for `userId`. Should that be used instead? Your output is consistent with what you wrote, that is, check for `userId` which is always `1`. You have a counter problem, though, that's why you get 3 and 0 instead of 4 and 1. I think you really meant to use `id` in your lookups. And then we need to fix the rest.

Comment: @bigbounty, count the no of true and false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your input data, it is so that:
userId 1, id 1 has 0 true, and 3 false
userId 1, id 2 has 1 true, and 1 false

Given the required output, it looks like you really want to use `id` rather than `userId` in your lookups. Besides that, there's an issue with accounting the first time you insert the `id` in the resulting dictionary. I would fix it like this:

```
todos_by_user_true = {}
todos_by_user_false = {}
# Increment complete TODOs count for each user.
for todo in todos:
    if todo["completed"]==True:
        try:
            # Increment the existing user's count.
            todos_by_user_true[todo["id"]] += 1
        except KeyError:
            # This user has not been seen. Set their count to 1.
            todos_by_user_true[todo["id"]] = 1
    elif todo["completed"]==False:
        try:
            # Increment the existing user's count.
            todos_by_user_false[todo["id"]] += 1
        except KeyError:
            # This user has not been seen. Set their count to 1.
            todos_by_user_false[todo["id"]] = 1
```

which (btw) is already what's in your comments.

Personally, I would check the dictionary for the key before insertion, instead of using `try..except`, like this:

```
todos_by_user_true = {}
todos_by_user_false = {}
# Increment complete TODOs count for each user.
for todo in todos:
    key = todo["id"]

    if todo["completed"]:  # true case
            # If `id` not there yet, insert it to 0
            if key not in todos_by_user_true:
               todos_by_user_true[key] = 0

            # increment
            todos_by_user_true[key] += 1

    else:  # false case

            # If `id` not there yet, insert it to 0
            if key not in todos_by_user_false:
               todos_by_user_false[key] = 0

            # increment
            todos_by_user_false[key] += 1
```

This gives out:

```
todos_by_user_true = {2:1}
todos_by_user_false = {1:3,2:1}
```

The logic being this, you cannot have:
todos_by_user_true = {1:0}

You account for the value when you find it; rather than iterating for `id` from a separate list.